# Remap the prefix key of text objects

Tags: vim

I'd like to change the prefix key of every text object command.
For instance:

```
aw -> qw
as -> qs
ap -> qp
```

and so on.

I have tried creating a very long list of `xnoremap` and `onoremap` that change one text object command per remap, but this is a very bad solution.

Is there a way I can do this easily?

Also, I would like all the old commands to be unmapped so that they don't interfere.

Comment: As the difficulty of this operation hints at you, you probably shouldn't do this. In no time, you'll have memorized the original keys, and they're not bad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd utilize a `for` loop to avoid the repetition:

```
for textObject in ['w', 's', 'p']
    execute printf('xnoremap q%s a%s', textObject, textObject)
    execute printf('onoremap q%s a%s', textObject, textObject)

    " Remove the original commands.
    execute printf('xnoremap a%s <Nop>', textObject)
    execute printf('onoremap a%s <Nop>', textObject)
endfor
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to change text object command?Do the default have any problems?If you have to do so,I think you can do like this:

```
nnoremap dqw daw
nnoremap dqs das
nnoremap dqp dap
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Other editors may have a model of functions and key-bindings, but vim does not.  Vim has built-in commands and user-defined mappings.  You can clear the latter, but there is no way to "unmap" a built-in command.

You could use the `'langmap'` option to swap the meaning of <kbd>a</kbd> and <kbd>q</kbd>.  This is very similar to one of the examples given under `:help 'langmap'`:

```
:set langmap=aq,qa
```

Read the help to see exactly what this does and does not affect.  Of course, this means that you will have to use a to start or end recording a macro and q to append.  You can try to undo that with

```
:nnoremap a a
:nnoremap q q
```

but I am not sure how well that will work.